# Why did I get a warning "expression is assigned to nothing" in ternary?

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I have some simple age classification code in which I try to use ternary operator. It worked, but VS Code shows a yellow line underneath the code saying that "expression ... is assigned to nothing". How do I get rid of it?

```
age = int(input("Input your age: "))
print("Teen") if age >= 15 else print("Kids")  # here
print("End program")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cpLo.png)

Comment: A ternary operator is beneficial in that it evaluates to the return value of the branch it selects. It's not an error, but overkill in your situation. You can use standard if/else.

Comment: Where you wrote "I tried rewrite the code but still not working" you should also show us the alternative version you tried.

Comment: `print("Teen" if age>=15 else "Kids")` is the correct way to use a ternary expression. It evaluates to "Teen" or "Kids" and *then* is printed.

Comment: @MarkTolonen That is syntactically correct, as is the O.P.'s code, but I would argue both are an obfuscating use of the ternary expression in this context. Your example is a defensible use of the ternary operator if there is literally nothing else predicated on the value of `age`, but in practice that is unlikely and the more straightforward `if age >= 15...else...` formulation is almost certainly preferable. The ternary operator tends to be over used (i.e., in situations where it isn't appropriate) so I don't encourage its use by new programmers.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `do_x if x else do_y` is an expression. You are normally expected to capture the result of an expression. Note that using `print()` isn't important. Any function you call could return one or more values. Using the ternary operator in this situation is only something you should do if writing code for an "obfuscated Python" contest. Instead simply do

```
if age >= 15:
  print("Teen")
else:
  print("Kids")
```